# Which is the best way to read_dir a network path in Rust?

Tags: rust

i can't read a path in my network using this code.
Maybe fs::read_dir work only for local dirs.

```
use std::fs;

fn main() {
     
    let paths = fs::read_dir("\\nbsvr01").unwrap();
    for path in paths { 
        println!("Name: {}", path.unwrap().path().display())
    }

}
```

Comment: Backslashes need to be escaped in Rust strings → try with `"\\\\nbsvr01"`.

Comment: @Jmb: Or `r"\\nbsvr01"`, that is easier to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rodrigo said, you can use `r"\\nbsvr01"`, which is more straightforward and easy to unserstand.

If you are not familiar with this, check [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#raw-string-literals) out:)